# Could not insert new outlet connection:

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, xcode9.3

[image: Could not insert new outlet connection: Could not find any information for the class named]

Continuously facing this error after updating to Xcode 9.3 Please help me

Comment: connect your outlet in 12th line ,surely  it will work

Comment: close Xcode and reopen.

Comment: or just do the opposite make outlet in your swift file and connect to the storyboard item

Answer (score 4):

I faced it just yesterday here is what I did

1. Cleaned the project
2. Deleted derived data
3. Closed Xcode opened it up and tried again. It worked.

Comment: You're may not aware of this, but this question is a common duplicate. Please avoid answering such questions.

Comment: I tried the same many times but no use

Comment: then sometimes it's because you of two outlets side by side I don't know why this happens. Just press enter between two outlets two or three time now make an outlet on this empty space

Answer (score 2):

Click on cancel. Now retry until the blue line appear in the center, middle or top of available outlets. This will happen when u already have an outlet of same type and drop new over that.

Comment: good capture....